# How to use LINQ to get multiple totals

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by

Let's say I have the following data in a database.

```
class Data
{
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public int ValueA { get; set; }
    public int ValueB { get; set; }
}
```

How can I write a LINQ query to get the sum of `ValueA` and also the sum of `ValueB` for all rows with `Category == 1`?

I know I could load all the data and then use `Sum` on the loaded data but would prefer to total them in the database.

I know I can use `group by` but I'm not grouping by anything. I just want these two totals from the data.

Comment: You can group by a constant value like 1.  Check out this related question http://stackoverflow.com//questions/10239987/get-sum-of-two-columns-in-one-linq-query-without-grouping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using EF, you can try this:

```
var result= context.Data.Where(d=>d.Category == 1)
                        .GroupBy(d=>d.Category)
                        .Select(g=>new {
                                         SumA=g.Sum(d=>d.ValueA),
                                         SumB=g.Sum(d=>d.ValueB)
                                       }
                               );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by a constant

```
var result = from d in context.Data
             where d.Category == 1
             group d by 1 into g
             select 
             {                  
                 ASum = g.Sum(d => d.ValueA), 
                 BSum = g.Sum(d => d.ValueB) 
             };
```

Or as octavioccl pointed out you can also group by `Category` since it will be a constant value because of the `where` clause.  But using a constant is how you can achieve what you want in the general case.